# Como obtener cantidad de elementos entre un rango de fecha

Tags: laravel

Colegas tengo una tabla llamada `soluciones` que almacena soluciones que se realizaron a un reporte de usuario. Esta tabla tiene una columna que es `fecha_inc`que almacena una fecha, además tengo una columna `user_id` que me almacena el usuario que realizo la solución. Estoy programando un gráfico que me permita saber cuantas soluciones aporto cada una persona por cada por mes, es decir cuantas veces aparece el usuario en la tabla por meses.

La consulta que programe es la siguiente:

```
$date_inicio  = date('Y').'-01-01';
$date_fin = date('Y').'-12-31';

$soluciones = Soluciones::where('user_id', $id)->whereBetween('fecha_inc', [$date_inicio, $date_fin])->get();
```

Pero no encuentro la manera de saber la cantidad de soluciones por meses que realizó el usuario. O sea, que la consulta me devuelva desglosado la cantidad de soluciones por meses.

Comment: Si sólo quieres la cantidad, puedes ejecutar la consulta con `->count()`en vez de `->get()`

Comment: Publique una respuesta de algo que desarrolle. Es que necesitaba la cantidad por meses y mostrar el mes con su cantidad. Gracias, no obstante puedes poner la consulta con tu propuesta asi otros pueden utilizarla. Gracias una vez mas

Answer (score 1):

Colegas desarrolle esta consulta y me dio resultado.

```
$soluciones = DB::table('soluciones')
                    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'), DB::raw('MONTH(soluciones.fecha_inc) AS mes'))
                    ->where('soluciones.user_id', '=', '1')
                    ->groupBy('mes')
                    ->orderBy('mes', 'asc')
                    ->get();
```

Publico la respuesta por si alguien tuvo mi duda.

Comment: como pudiera MONTH(soluciones.fecha_inc) AS mes, devolverme al arreglo de meses que que se genera en la consulta con el nombre de los meses. Alguna idea colegas